# connect two Project in c# (create plugin in Navisworks)

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2015, autodesk-navisworks

I want to create a plugin using c# in the Navisworks environment. By clicking on this plugin, a form will be opened that contains several buttons and by clicking on each of them, the file related to it will be displayed in the form of an Excel file.

1. I wrote a code in visual studio that by creating different forms and buttons, you can click on each of them to open the Excel file related to it.
2. I wrote another code in the Visual Studio to create a plugin in Navis.
   But I do not know why when I run the program, the form I created and the plugin are not displayed in the Navisworks environment. The form is displayed in the same Visual Studio environment.

[image]

Comment: Can you post code rather than a snapshot of code?